# How to handle errors (unable to locate element) in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, click

I am writting bot using Selenium for a game where is a lot of clicking. 
Sometimes it shows error Unable to locate element:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div/div[1]/header/div/div[1]/a
```

I have correct Xpath but sometimes it gives me an error in different parts in my code. It is not that I have one mistake and it always show error in one place. My problem is that those errors are random. I am handling it like this:

```
try:
    secondPhoto = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '/html/body/span/section/main/article/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]')
    secondPhotoOpen = ActionChains(self.driver)
    secondPhotoOpen.move_to_element(secondPhoto)
    secondPhotoOpen.click()
    secondPhotoOpen.perform()
except:
    time.sleep(3)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '/html/body/span/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]').click()
```

This is not a ideal solution. It still shows errors but less frequently.
I am also using `time.sleep`. Usually errors show up when I am doing something else on internet or I have lags(this is the reason why I am using `time.sleep`) Now, I have about 50 `.click()` in my code and for all clicks I am doing try except but still it is not working correctly.

1. Do you have an effective solution for this? How to write a code that use `.click()` to be 100% sure it works regardless lags, other
   browser activity?
2. How to wait for full load of next page/image after click() ( I am
   using time.sleep)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WebDriverWait`:

```
btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "element_id")))
btn.click()
```

this will wait at least 10 seconds, until element will be clickable and only then clicks on it. Also I would recommend to read [this](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html). With `WebDriverWait` you don't have to have hard coded pauses.